# How to remove docker aufs folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I've uninstalled docker with the following command

`sudo apt-get purge docker-engine`

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine`

The above command works fine, no problem. But when I try to run **`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`** as instructed in [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#uninstallation), I get the following error

**`rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/04fc3de09910bf8fae3d0430b0debbf3032d480bef4ced9f40b1f532bf478ef9': Is a directory`**

What should I do to remove this content?

Comment: I don't want to uninstall docker, but I saw that the `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` folder is now 10GB, how can I clean that? It shouldn't take that much space. Is it safe to remove the content?

Comment: as you want to completely uninstall it, you can try removing all the contaners and images first then uninstall docker. @Fla

Comment: No, as said, I don't want to uninstall it, I just want to free some space. I used [this script](https://gist.github.com/justlaputa/a50908d4c935f39c39811aa5fa9fba33) but now my containers have an error... `docker: Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9677d6d4a456b86613547d25638a181ac73db977278a05167cb5821b7507bc33-init: invalid argument.`

Comment: I dropped the aufs folder and that solved it.

Answer (score 4):

- First remove docker-engine using `sudo apt remove docker-engine`
- Reboot.
- Then remove `/var/lib/docker/aufs` with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs`.
- Perform the Ubuntu upgrade with `sudo do-release-upgrade`
- You can now re-install docker-engine using `sudo apt install docker-engine` (or don't, your choice)

Answer (score 0):

Try **sudo su** and then **rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/04fc3de09910bf8fae3d0430b0debbf3032d480bef4ced9f40b1f532bf478ef9**